# Turkey Transit Visa

Tags: transit-visas, turkey, filipino-citizens

I am Filipino national. I would like to know if I need transit visa in Istanbul. I am traveling to Brazil from Kuwait to Istanbul via AtlasJet, then to São Paulo via Swiss Air or Iberia Airlines.

Do I need to have a transit visa for Turkey if I will collect my luggage in Istanbul from AtlasJet and check my luggage again to Swiss Air for my Istanbul to São Paulo flight?

Comment: Are the two flights on the same ticket or different tickets?

Comment: Different tickets. Kuwait to Istanbul (Atlasjet) & Istanbul to Sao Paulo (Swiss Air or Iberia Airlines). Thanks.

Comment: Not sure this is a total duplicate then, given the change in airlines on separate tickets with luggage.

Comment: I am coming from Kuwait. My flights would be Kuwait to Istanbul. Once I reach Istanbul, I will pull out my luggage from Atlasjet and transfer them to Swiss Air or Iberia Airlines for my flight Istanbul to Sao Paulo.

Comment: @ZachLipton IST is quite possibly the only airport in the world with _airside_ baggage claim. It's possible to claim baggage and change airlines without passing through passport control.